# AEM 6.0 crx/de goes blank every now and then

Tags: aem, crx

We use AEM 6.0 for a client and crx/de goes blank every now and then.
Not sure why and the frequency that it happens , but on a random check of every 3 or 4 hours the crx/de page of a publish instance does not even load the crx/de page , it just shows blank. 
Unable to get the logs as it is a restricted environment(sorry about that) , but the error shows - crx/de - Resource not found.

Comment: if your publish instance is behind of any dispatcher check your crx/de allowed or restricted to access. we have a privilege to block certain paths which cannot be exposed in publish instances via dispatcher.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the quick response. However I am trying to access this via the Publisher and not via Dispatcher. So no blocking applicable here i guess.

Comment: means you are accessing via IP address .?

Comment: Yes, directly the publisher IP:port/crx/de and it is blank. In logs it shows crx/de resource not found.

Comment: I have the same issue from time to time. And I usually get around it by using /crx/de/ or /crx/de/index.jsp directly. In more recent versions I sometimes need to login through system/console or crx/packmgr first to be able to get crx/de to resolve. I've never looked into the core issue with this as the workaround is relatively simple.

Comment: @ Randy Orton, It will be helpful to debug, if you can provide a detailed logs in AEM for the url request trace.

Comment: Hi I am really sorry as the logs could not be extracted without client permission , however wanted everyone to know that i found the cause. It was due to a hotfix which i had installed, to hide Jetty version in the Server header. So once i uninstalled it , it worked. WIll raise a ticket with adobe support to check the same. Thanks folks.